AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: context not currently entered; can't exit . CLS hooks in Nodejs version 20
Am upgrading my node version from 12 to 20 version and cls-hook version is 4.2.2
and now am getting the following error
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: context not currently entered; can't exit in Nodejs
the following is my cls middleware code
const cls = require('cls-hooked')
//const uuidv4 = require('uuid');
//uuidv4.v4();
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const clsNamespace = cls.createNamespace('app')

exports.clsMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {

  try {
    
    clsNamespace.bind(req)
    clsNamespace.bind(res)

    const requestID = uuidv4()

    clsNamespace.run(() => {
      clsNamespace.set('req:x-requestID', requestID);
      // other attributes
      next()
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }


}

exports.vars = clsNamespace;

and am requiring and using it before any routes
Moreover this error happens as when i hit endpoints in my app.
I have also try to directly use middleware in my main app.js file but still its giving same error like below
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: context not currently entered; can't exit. 
Namespace {
  name: 'localsession',
  active: null,
  _set: [],
  id: -1,
  _contexts: Map(31) {
    2308 => {
      _ns_name: 'localsession',
      id: 2305,
      'request:id': undefined,
      'request:x-app-language': 'EN',
     
    },
    2309 => {
      _ns_name: 'localsession',
      id: 2305,
      'request:id': undefined,
      'request:x-app-language': 'EN',
      
    },

